# Can I use a 1/8 thimble with 1/16 wire rope?

Tags: hanging

I'm hanging some items from a ceiling.

The hardware stores around me all have plenty of 1/8 wire rope and 1/8 fittings, but when it comes to 1/16 size, aside from the wire rope itself, the only 1/16 fittings they have are the sleeves (aka ferrules).

I just need to make some loop ends using thimbles, which will attach to generic carabiners and/or screw hooks.

Just want to confirm whether using 1/6 wire rope in a 1/8 [thimble](https://www.nixalite.com/SiteContent/NixaliteFiles/Families/217/THIMBLE%20SS%20FORGED.jpg) is okay. I think if the wire fits within the thimble, then it does the job.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's OK. It may look a bit funky to have a smaller cable in there, but the functionality will not be affected.